# Bit mask in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, bit-manipulation, bitmask

Is something like the following code possible within a shell script?

```
var1=0xA (0b1010)
if ( (var1 & 0x3) == 0x2 ){
    ...perform action...
}
```

Just to make my intentions 100% clear my desired action would be to check bits of var1 at 0x3 (0b0011) and make sure that it equals 0x2 (0b0010)

```
 0b1010
&0b0011
_______
 0b0010 == 0x2 (0b0010)
```

Comment: Generally non-completely-trivial calculations are performed through an external command, such as `bc` or `dc` or `expr`.

Comment: This is a completely trivial calculation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bit manipulation is supported in POSIX arithmetic expressions:

```
if [ $(( var1 & 0x3 )) -eq $(( 0x2 )) ]; then
```

However, it's a bit simpler use an arithmetic statement in `bash`:

```
if (( (var1 & 0x3) == 0x2 )); then
```

Comment: 0x3 == 0x2 will always be false in the "simpler" command. Braces around (var1 & 0x3) required.

Comment: Thanks; I forgot (or didn't consider) that `&` had lower precedence than `==`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is entirely possible:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=0xA # (0b1010)
if (( (var1 & 0x3) == 0x2 ))
then
  echo "Match"
fi
```